# Rhetoric difference: a more muscular NSF vs. a more powerful NSF

Tags: word-usage

The word "muscular" in the phrase "a more muscular NSF" appears to mean "powerful." The question of this thread is: Rhetorically, what is the difference between "a more muscular NSF" and "a more powerful NSF"?

"Muscular" hints the use of muscle and thus sounds a bit more informal than "powerful" to me. Plus, it sounds a bit sarcastic because a mission like NSF excels in using its brain or its wisdom rather than its muscle. I am not sure.

Rhetorics is a a hard part for English learners to crack.

> First round of hearings by Congress back **a more muscular NSF**
> The U.S. Congress this week got its first chance to weigh in on proposals to expand the mission and massively boost the budget of the National Science Foundation (NSF), and the initial response was positive.

> Source: [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/first-round-hearings-congress-back-more-muscular-nsf)

Comment: Writers like variation and figures of speech.

Comment: Sorry. My question appears to remain unanswered.